# If two WASD keys are pressed, the character moves in the direction of the first keypress - but continues in that direction once it has been lifted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, character

*I am new to Unity so please be kind*

So I want my character to move in the direction of the last key pressed. If I press W (up) and D (right) at the same time, the player will move in the direction of what came first. If I release that key and continue to hold the key that was pressed 2nd, the character doesn't change direction until you release said key and repress. This is ruining the feel of my game and I would like some help fixing this problem:)
Here is my character controller script:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator anim;
    Vector2 movement; 

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); //gets axis as vector2 
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
        anim.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);  //sets animation parameters
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 1 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == -1 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 1 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == -1) 
//If statement to set the correct idle animation (idle right, left, down) based off last direction.
        {
            anim.SetFloat("LastHorizontal", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
            anim.SetFloat("LastVertical", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

        }
    }  
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (Mathf.Abs(movement.x) > Mathf.Abs(movement.y)) //if statement disables diagonal movement
        {
            movement.y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            movement.x = 0;
        }

        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //applies movement to player
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small thing to improve your code, you seem to use Input.GetAxisRaw in the same function multiple times. Consider calling it once and saving it to a variable, it should improve both the code's readability and efficiency.

Comment: Also what exactly will be the difference between `anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);` and `anim.SetFloat("LastHorizontal", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));` ? For WASD they will always be full values `-1`, `0` or `1` anyway ...

Comment: In the FixedUpdate method you are trying to disable diagonal movement but your if statement is wrong. If the player is trying to move diagonally movement.x and y will probably be equal. This means your else statement will be executed, thus making the player move horizontally.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used Unity, but here's two suggestions. First, your question might be better suited for [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com). Secondly, as @66Gramms pointed out, the reason appears to be due to your `else` function forcing the player to move horizontally. How often does `FixedUpdate()` run?  If it runs when keys are pressed, it might not update even if the keys change because of the initial value it received. Is there any way to have it execute when a key is pressed _or_ released? Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing movement only on one axis in yout fixed update, I'd try forcing the direction vector for each key. So your code would look like this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        movement.y = 1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        movement.y = -1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        movement.x = -1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        movement.x = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        movement = Vector3.zero
    }
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //applies movement to player
}
```

The result of this should be your character not being able to move diagonaly